# Get opened pages in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I want to know whether it's possible to get Information about opened pages in Chrome (page title, url) from third party app (not extensions)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try use the Accessibility techniques. Chrome implemented IAccessible interfaces in Chromium that any screen readers can read. If you implement a screen reader like application you can easily get those data. But to do that, you would need to understand how accessible applications work.

Or you can check out ManagedSpy, where the source code is provided: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/). In the Web Sessions list, it shows all the URLs that are accessed, and the program (and PID) that accessed them, including Chrome. If you click on one of the URLs and look under Inspectors on the right, then Text View on the lower section, you can see the `<title>` section for each page.

Comment: That'll work, although I don't think that's what he's really looking for.  AFAIK, Chrome has no such API for apps to use, and mucking about in their memory space yourself is a bad idea if you want your app to be stable.